# Trouble Creating Dataframe from Arrays

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe

I want to create a DataFrame with separate columns for PY and ST, however the DataFrame is created with index values of PY.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

K = 8000 

ST = np.linspace(7000,9000,num=50)  

PO = 50 

PY = np.maximum(ST-K-PO,0)

pd.DataFrame(PY,ST)
```

Is there a way to create the DataFrame with default index starting from 0 and 2 columns of PY and ST.

Comment: Your index values are ST not PY.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(PY,ST)),columns=["py","st"])`

Comment: Thank you.   Appreciate your help.  Is there a reason why first column is taken index ?

Comment: Yeah index is the second argument to pandas.DataFrame. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html